# Token error causing issues to this page

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling

Whenever I add the two together, it creates an unexpected token of } on my page. what is wrong and what am I missing? I looked over everything. It seems both work separately.

Also when I look at my console, it gives me a line that an error is causing from, but if I click that it shows nothing.

Any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // On Load Show
    $('.draft_landing_wrapper').hide();
    $(".light_admin,.dark_gray_overlay").fadeIn("slow", function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(".light_admin,.dark_gray_overlay").fadeOut("slow");
        }, 10000);
        $(".light_admin").animate({
            paddingBottom: '150px',
            paddingTop: '150px',
            marginTop: '-150px'
        }, function () {
            $('.draft_landing_wrapper').delay(1000).fadeIn('fast');
        });
    });
});
$('.admin_popup').on('click', function () {
    $(".light_admin,.dark_gray_overlay").fadeIn("slow", function () {
        $(".light_admin").animate({
            paddingBottom: '150px',
            paddingTop: '150px',
            marginTop: '-150px'
        });
    });
});
$('.draft_close').on('click', function () {
    $(".light_admin,.dark_gray_overlay").fadeOut("slow");
    $(".light_admin").css({
        paddingBottom: '0px',
        paddingTop: '0px',
        marginTop: '0px'
    });
});
```

Then this

```
//Timer
var times = [];
var counter_interval;
var $time_left = $('.time-left');
var $button = $('.start-pause');
$(document).ready(function () {
    // timer length in seconds
    var timer_length = 45;
    $('body').on('click', '.start-pause', function () {
        // are we starting or stopping?
        var starting = times.length % 2 == 0;
        times.push(Date.now());
        if (starting) {
            $button.html('Pause');
            counter_interval = setInterval(function () {
                var time_left = Math.floor(timer_length - sum_elapsed());
                if (time_left < 1) {
                    clearInterval(counter_interval);
                    return finished();
                }
                //$time_left.html(time_left);
                $time_left.html(secToMinTxt(time_left));

            }, 100);
        } else {
            $button.html('Resume');
            clearInterval(counter_interval);
        }
    });
    function pad(num) {
        var str = "" + num;
        var pad = "00";
        return pad.substring(0, pad.length - str.length) + str;
    }
    function secToMinTxt(seconds) {
        var min = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
        var sec = seconds % 60;
        return pad(min) + ":" + pad(sec);
    }
    var sum_elapsed = function () {
        sum = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 1) {
                sum += (times[i] - times[i - 1]);
            }
            if (i == (times.length - 1)) {
                sum += (Date.now() - times[i]);
            }
        }
        // convert milliseconds to seconds
        return sum / 1000;
    };
    var finished = function () {
        $button.attr('disabled', 'disabled').html('Finished');
        $time_left.html("Time's Up!!");
    };
});
});
```

Comment: How do you add the two together?

Comment: At first I just entered the timer code without the doc ready code. I just placed it right under it and that is when the issues started. I then tried the doc ready code over the timer code, but that didn't help.

Comment: Remove last line: '});' - syntax error is in question.... in second script.

Comment: That makes the pop up work again, but the timer still doesn't work

Comment: add your HTML sample.